# Jquery Testmonial: Working with two items but not with more

Tags: jquery

I wrote a code to be used with the testimonials of my visitors. It works correctly when one or two testimonials are inside the code, but when that amount increases, rather than displaying one comment at a time, the script is showing two testimonials at the same time. Could someone help me solve this problem?
[Working example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/acxrsbmh/2/) and a [bad working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/acxrsbmh/3/) examples.

HTML CODE

```
<div id="testmonials-wrapper">
<div id="testmonials-area"></div>
<div id="testmonials-text">MY TESTMONIALS</div>
<div id="testmonials-label">
<div id="testmonial-center">

<div id="test-rotator">
<div class="roter" style="display: none;">
<div class="left-quote"></div>  
<div class="center-quote">TEXT 01</div>
<div class="right-quote"></div>
<div class="testmonials-name">- Username 01 -</div>
</div>
<div class="roter" style="display: block;">
<div class="left-quote"></div>  
<div class="center-quote">Text 02.</div>
<div class="right-quote"></div>
<div class="testmonials-name">- Username 02 -</div>
</div>


</div>
</div>  
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var carouselInt = '';
var carouDiv = function(){
carouselInt = setInterval(function() { 
  $("#test-rotator > .roter:first")
  .fadeIn(500)
  .next()
  .fadeOut(0)
  .end()
  .appendTo("#test-rotator"); 
},2000);

};
$(carouDiv());//Initialise the carousel function

$("#test-rotator").hover(function(){ //Stop the carousel on hover
 clearInterval(carouselInt);
  },function(){
  carouDiv();
});
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #251a17;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-image: url('../snippets/neb01.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover; 
}
#testmonials-wrapper {
    height: 150px;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
#testmonials-wrapper-pinturas {
    height: 10px;
}
.left-quote {
    width: 39px;
    height: 67px;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(../snippets/left-quote.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.testmonials-name {

    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
}
#brown-divider {
    height: 61px;
    background-color: #251a17;
    padding-top: 12px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-image: url(../snippets/testmonial-shadow.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#testminials-write {
    width: 243px;
    height: 52px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-image: url(../snippets/testmonials-button.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.right-quote {
    width: 39px;
    height: 67px;
    float: left;
    background-image: url(../snippets/right-quote.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    clear: right;
}
#testminials-write #envienos {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 42px;
    font-size: 12px;

}
.roter {
    display: none;
}
#testmonials-text {
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: What's the question? We're not a free debugging service. Please read the [help]

Comment: I believe `$("#test-rotator > .roter:first")`  is the culprit as you are selecting first of that type.

Comment: Thank you for your help @RajeevRanjan. I was able to solve the problem by changing a part of the css.

Comment: Please post your answer.. @V.Salles

Comment: Answer posted. Thank U.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem, simple add this code into css sheet:

```
#test-rotator {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 35px; 
}
```

And into javascript code, change:

```
.fadeOut(0)
```

to:

```
.fadeOut(500)
```

Fiddle example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/acxrsbmh/5/)